# nearby places in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform

I have to develop a website on which user enter latitude and longitude of a particular location. based on latitude and longitude I should fetch nearby locations and display it on google maps. As of now, I displayed the nearby locations for one type eg.restaurants, Now I want to fetch more than one type using place-API.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post what you have tried so far to achieve your requirement. Kindly refer, [how to ask a question in so](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither searching with multiple types nor excluding a type from query is possible right now. Google's policy is simply forcing people to send more requests. Sometimes people pay for things they don't want or double/triple for what they could achieve with only one query.

Although there's no searching option for second,third parameter, you can still get what you want, with of course paying for it.

This is how a regular NearbySearch request looks like;

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

service.nearbySearch(
      {location: latLng, radius: 500, type: ['store']},
      function(results, status) {
        if (status !== 'OK') return;
            // results
        };
      });
```

If you want to get multiple types, you have to send a request for each type which would look like this;

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

service.nearbySearch(
      {location: latLng, radius: 500, type: ['store']},
      function(results, status) {
        if (status !== 'OK') return;
            // results for store
            service.nearbySearch(
                {location:latLng, radius: 1500, type : ['fire_station']},
            function(fireStationResult, fireStationStatus) {
                // firestation results here
                // and so on.
            }
            )
        };
      });
```

You **have to** use nearbySearch request in eachother's blocks since it work async.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for multiple types is **not** currently supported by the Places API's [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests).

There is an existing feature request for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112291747. I'd recommend you to comment your use-case in there and star it to receive updates.